# different jshint options before and after grunt concatenation but before minification?

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, jshint

**tldr;** What are the locations or wildcard searches that will apply specific jshint options to be used after concatenation but before the files are minified?

Building an app using yeoman, I have read the documentation for [grunt-contrib-jshint](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jshint) and I can see where to amend the specific linting options per file (incl wildcard matching) distinct from defaults

```
jshint: {
    options: { … },
    },
    uses_defaults: ['dir1/**/*.js', 'dir2/**/*.js'],
    with_overrides: {
      options: { … },
      files: {
        src: ['dir3/**/*.js', 'dir4/**/*.js']
      },
    }
},
```

and also to run jshint before and after concetatenation in a grunt process.

```
jshint: {
    beforeconcat: ['src/foo.js', 'src/bar.js'],
    afterconcat: ['dist/output.js']
}
```

if have added the following to my Gruntfile.js:

```
jshint: {
        options: {
            jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
        },
        uses_defaults: [
            'Gruntfile.js',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '!<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/vendor/*',
            'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
        ],
        beforeconcat: [
            'Gruntfile.js',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '!<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/vendor/*',
            'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
        ],
        afterconcat: [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/*.js'
        ],
        with_overrides: {
            options: {
                unused: true,
                undef: true
            },
            files: {
                src: [
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/*.js'
                ]
            }
        }
```

But this always trips out when it tries to lint the minified files in `dist`. In fact I think it is the minified files from the previous grunt build process.

I have looked at [the answer given to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13547748/1100265), but it isn't clear if that applies here as it doesn't refer to concatenation, or perhaps it does but only by location. So either by extending that answer, or as a specific variation related to my method above (from the docs) what are the locations or wildcard searches that will apply specific jshint options to be used after concatenation but before the files are minified?

Comment: If it is the files from the previous build process then make sure to run a grunt clean task first.

Comment: What would the benefit be linting processed JavaScript files if you've already linted the source files used to generate the processed files? In particular what is the benefit to linting minified files?

Comment: it was more about the linting of concatenated files in this instance